# Rails one controller for backend and frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i have working backend for example im able to manage categories like **/backend/category/1**
but i also need let user list products.. so if user will type **/category/1** (products list of category 1) what **html.erb** and how i can show him or perhaps i need 2 controllers ? Im beginner so please tell me somehow simple thank you :-)

My idea is url like 
/category/1 - list all products of category 1

/category/1/product/2 - will show product 2 info

or

/category/1/2 - i dont know what is best practice or recommended :p

The URL look like is not priority, important is that user have no right to show action to backend category controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need separate controllers, you can block off views/actions individually. A common way is to run a filter before certain actions. That way you can keep authentication and controller logic separate.

If you want a simple way to make `/backend` only available to yourself I recommend following the example for [basic http auth given in the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html). The line where you define which actions require a password is:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index
```

which says to block off all actions *except* `index`. You can flip this around by using

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :edit
```

I don’t recommend using the latter because it’s easy to forget to block off an action this way.

If you have a `user` model in your Rails application that stores if a user is an admin or not, it works very similar. Let’s assume your model answers to `user.admin?`. Then your setup would look something like:

```
# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoryController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_admin, except: [:index]
  # …
end

# app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
module SessionsHelper
  def require_admin
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Setting up the session helper, controller and the like is covered quite nicely on [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top)

Comment: thank you, i already have authentication with action exceptions but now i know that one controller is enough and i will create /backend url via routes